# AWS auto scale ECS task and EC2 instance both at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Can AWS handles auto scaling of a ECS task and EC2 instance both at the same time?

If instance has not enough space to start a new ECS task it should be able to spawn a new instance automatically, is this kind of setup possible in AWS?

I know how to setup auto scaling for instance and tasks individually, but i'm not sure how it can be combined together?

I can see some documentation mentioning about creating AWS lambda function to handle this, but it sounds like a custom handling.

I hope there are some Standard way of doing this?

Comment: By enough space, you mean memory? and by task means a container inside ECS Cluster?

Comment: CPU units & yes, it's container inside ECS Cluster

Comment: What is your definition of a "task"? Are you referring to an Amazon ECS task? (Your question did not mention ECS.)